# File upload, factory_girl & database_cleaner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

In my model, I have to choose an asset, saved in a `editorial_asset` table.

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :editorial_asset do
    editorial_asset { fixture_file_upload("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/files/fakeUp.png", "image/png") }
  end
end
```

so I have attached in my model factory an association on `:editorial_asset`

Upload work great, but take too much time (1s per example)

I'm wonder if it's possible to create uploads one time before each examples, and say in the factory: "find instead of create"

But the problem with database_cleaner, I cannot except tables with `:transaction`, truncation take 25sec instead of 40ms !

## EDIT

The factory that need an asset

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :actu do
    sequence(:title) {|n| "Actu #{n}"}
    sequence(:subtitle) {|n| "Sous-sitre #{n}"}

    body Lipsum.paragraphs[3]

    # Associations
    user
    # editorial_asset
  end
end
```

The model spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Actu do
  before(:all) do
    @asset = create(:editorial_asset)
  end

  after(:all) do
    EditorialAsset.destroy_all
  end

  it "has a valid factory" do
    create(:actu).should be_valid
  end

end
```

So a working way is

```
  it "has a valid factory" do
    create(:actu, editorial_asset: @asset).should be_valid
  end
```

but there's no way to inject automatically association ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using RSpec, you could use a `before(:all)` block to set up these records once. However, anything done in a before-all block is **NOT** considered part of the transaction, so you will have to delete anything from the DB yourself in an after-all block.

Your factory for the model that has an association to the editorial asset could then, yes, try to first find one before creating it. Instead of doing something like `association :editorial_asset` you could do:

```
editorial_asset { EditorialAsset.first || Factory.create(:editorial_asset) }
```

Your rspec tests could then look like this:

```
before(:all) do
    @editorial = Factory.create :editorial_asset
end

after(:all) do
    EditorialAsset.destroy_all
end

it "already has an editorial asset." do
    model = Factory.create :model_with_editorial_asset
    model.editorial_asset.should == @editorial
end
```

Read more about before and after blocks on the Rspec GitHub wiki page or on the Relish documentation:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec

Comment: I edited my question with my specs, I think it's good, But with database_cleaner, I cannot say find or create, everything is destroyed

Comment: Using `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {except: ["editorial_assets"]}` work great with find or create. But cleaning is very slow now. I'm running Archlinux with postgresql and seems it's linux related

Comment: it's EXT4 related. After some tweaks, it's more faster, but my User spec with 15 examples take 2sec with truncation instead of 40ms with transaction. I think I will try with reiserfs

Comment: And a `fsync off` at postgresql.conf can help with slow truncation